# Infinite auto-login loop when using child sites

Tags: bug, login, firefox, auto-login, osx

I appear to be having issues when visiting child sites from my Network Profile.

When I go to the child site (seen so far on SO and SU) I appear to not be logged in:

[image]

After clicking "log in", it takes me to the login page and quickly auto-redirects me:

[image]

When I'm redirected back to the site, I'm again not logged in.

Not sure what additional details are required - I'm on OSX Yosemite, using Firefox 36.0.1. I don't have any addons that would relate to redirects, cookie or session changes or generally rewrite a page.

When I check out my cookies on SU, I appear to have one for acct and another for usr both for ".superuser.com". Unsure if these are private, so I won't post them. Interestingly, there also appears to be a usr cookie for "superuser.com", however this one has no value, whilst the other two do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuked all cookies whilst on SU and reloaded the page, it auto logged me in (without being at the login page) and all worked when I reloaded again. Definitely a cookie issue, unfortunately I was in a rush and didn't take the time to work out which cookie it was.

Deleting cookies should resolve the issue for any other users who experience this though.